# Highcharts access drilldown data from event click

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display the drilldown series pie chart data on click.  I'm able to display the pie chart series name the user clicks on but not the drill down data.

Here is an example:

```
$(function () {
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the slices to view versions. Source: netmarketshare.com.'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events:{
                  click: function (event) {
                       alert(event.point.name)
                  }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            drilldown: 'Chrome'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: 'Firefox'
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77,
            drilldown: 'Safari'
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91,
            drilldown: 'Opera'
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2,
            drilldown: null
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                ['v11.0', 24.13],
                ['v8.0', 17.2],
                ['v9.0', 8.11],
                ['v10.0', 5.33],
                ['v6.0', 1.06],
                ['v7.0', 0.5]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            id: 'Chrome',
            data: [
                ['v40.0', 5],
                ['v41.0', 4.32],
                ['v42.0', 3.68],
                ['v39.0', 2.96],
                ['v36.0', 2.53],
                ['v43.0', 1.45],
                ['v31.0', 1.24],
                ['v35.0', 0.85],
                ['v38.0', 0.6],
                ['v32.0', 0.55],
                ['v37.0', 0.38],
                ['v33.0', 0.19],
                ['v34.0', 0.14],
                ['v30.0', 0.14]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: [
                ['v35', 2.76],
                ['v36', 2.32],
                ['v37', 2.31],
                ['v34', 1.27],
                ['v38', 1.02],
                ['v31', 0.33],
                ['v33', 0.22],
                ['v32', 0.15]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            id: 'Safari',
            data: [
                ['v8.0', 2.56],
                ['v7.1', 0.77],
                ['v5.1', 0.42],
                ['v5.0', 0.3],
                ['v6.1', 0.29],
                ['v7.0', 0.26],
                ['v6.2', 0.17]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            id: 'Opera',
            data: [
                ['v12.x', 0.34],
                ['v28', 0.24],
                ['v27', 0.17],
                ['v29', 0.16]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
});
```

Instead of alert(event.point.name) I want to access the drilldown series data corresponding to the id the user clicks on.

Using the console.log I thought this would work (this.chart.series[0].data[0]) but it displays the series data and not the drilldown.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing drilldown.js which is needed to drilldown the pie.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
```

See the [Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/LjyLgbxh/2/)

Comment: Already had that.  Apologies for not including all of the code.  I just want to be able to access the drill down data on click.  Here is sample fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/staplemx/czpwgbmw/4/

Comment: What I mean to say is on click I want to alert the drilldown data and not the drillup series data.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer:
this.chart.options.drilldown.series[0].data[0]